# Set selected state for UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am working on my app, when clicking on 1 cell, its background should turn to blue and if clicking on other cell, the previous cell will reset its background color.
This is my setSelected func

```
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        if selected {
            borderView.applyBorder(color: .darkGray, width: 1)
            borderView.backgroundColor = .blue
        } else {
            borderView.applyBorder(color: .lightGray, width: 1.0)
            borderView.backgroundColor = .white
        }
    }
```

But when I test it, cells will have blue background and they don't reset if I click other ones.
[image]

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted... the problem lies somewhere in your code that you *did not* show us.

Answer (score 0):

Throw away your existing code. You cannot do this in a *cell* based way; you must do it in a *row* based way, which means your must implement it through the *data model* on which the contents of your table depend.

1. In the delegate of your table view, implement the table view delegate method `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)`. In that method, change something in the table view's *model* such that every row knows whether it is now selected or not, and call the table view's `reloadData` so that it will generate new cells.
2. In your table view's data source's `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`, configure the appearance of the requested cell as you provide it, in accordance with the information in the *model* for that row.

Comment: For a working example, see the downloadable project at https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch08p431pickACell and look at how I make tapping a cell correspond to which cell has the checkmark. This is completely parallel to your desire to make tapping a cell correspond to which cell is blue.

Answer (score -1):

In this scenario, it's a single selection table. I didn't see your code for setting up the table view, so I suppose you're using an incorrect property.

```swift
//This property is false by default
tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
```

Then it should work normally. And to get the selected row for other purposes.

```swift
//There is a property to get all selected rows. However, it's single selection table, so using this
if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
    //TODO
}
```

But this approach has a drawback. When you want to select a cell by default, i.e., on `viewDidLoad`. Instead of just setting the `selected` property inside the model to true like @matt said in his answer. You must set by method `tableView.selectRow`. It means you let table view handle selection state, and your model is just for showing up information.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @son, I got it working by remove table.deSelect in my didSelectRowAt

Comment: Let table view do its job in this case, you don't need to handle 2 delegate methods: select and deselect.